# How to trigger animation in React.js? "TypeError: Cannot read property 'startAnimation' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, animation, onclick, state

I'm trying to launch animation in my to-do.list app from icon onCLick, but I'm getting a type error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startAnimation' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/adm/Desktop/toDo-List/finalize/finalize/src/listitems.js:25
  22 |            
  23 |       
  24 |        <FontAwesomeIcon
> 25 |         className="faicons" onClick={this.startAnimation}   
     | ^  26 |         onClick={() => {props.deleteItem(item.key)}}
  27 | 
  28 |         
View compiled
ListItems
C:/Users/adm/Desktop/toDo-List/finalize/finalize/src/listitems.js:11
   8 |    
   9 |    const items = props.items;
  10 | 
> 11 |    const listitems = items.map(item =>
     | ^  12 |    {
  13 |        return <div className ="list" key={item.key}>
  14 |          <p>
```

This is the listitems.js where "FontAwesomeIcon" onClick should trigger the animation:

```
import React from 'react';
import './listitems.css'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import Ilotulitus from './Animation.js'


function ListItems(props){

    const items = props.items;

    const listitems = items.map(item =>
    {
        return <div className ="list" key={item.key}>
          <p>
         <input type="text" 
          id={item.key}
          value={item.text} 
          onChange={(e)=>{
             props.setUpdate(e.target.value,item.key)}}/>
        <span>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
         className="faicons" onClick={this.startAnimation}   
         onClick={() => {props.deleteItem(item.key)}}


         icon="trash" />

        </span>
     </p>

        </div>
    })
    return(
        <div>
            {listitems}

            </div>
    )
}
export default ListItems;
```

I have defined the startAnimation function in my App.js, actual animation is in my css-file.

```
  class App extends React.Component{

      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          items:[],
          currentItem:{
            text:'',
            key:'',
            classNames: ''}
        }

        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
        this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
        this.setUpdate = this.setUpdate.bind(this);
        this.startAnimation = this.startAnimation.bind(this);


      }
      startAnimation = () => {
        const { classNames } = this.state;

        this.setState({ classNames: "animation" });
      };

          handleInput(e) {
            this.setState({
              currentItem:{
                text: e.target.value,
                key: Date.now()

              }        
            })
          }

      addItem(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const newItem = this.state.currentItem;
        console.log(newItem);
        if(newItem.text!==""){
          const newItems=[...this.state.items, newItem];
          this.setState({
            items:newItems,
            currentItem:{
              text:'',
              key:''
            }
          })
        }
      }

     deleteItem(key){
        const filteredItems = this.state.items.filter(item =>
          item.key!==key);
        this.setState({
          items: filteredItems  
        })
      }
      setUpdate(text,key){
        console.log("items:"+this.state.items);
        const items = this.state.items;
        items.map(item=>{      
          if(item.key===key){
            console.log(item.key +"    "+key)
            item.text= text;
          }
        })
        this.setState({
          items: items
        })
      }


        render() {

       return (

        <div className="App">
          <Hola />

         <header>

           <form id="to-do-form" onSubmit={this.addItem}>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text"
             value={this.state.currentItem.text} onChange={this.handleInput}/>
             <button type="submit">Add</button>

           </form>
         </header>
         <ListItems items={this.state.items} deleteItem={this.deleteItem} setUpdate={this.setUpdate} startAnimation={this.startAnimation}/>
         </div>

      );
     }

    }

    export default App
```

;

The functionality purpose is, once user deletes an item from app, the animation plays. Should the states be defined in listitmes.js also?

Answer (score 0):

Change `onClick={this.startAnimation}` to `onClick={props.startAnimation}`. Your `App` component is a "Class component" whereas your `ListItems` component is a "Function component". [Here's an article I found on the differences](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108), but a quick search should give you many more results. The official [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) is also a good place to look. The main takeaway is that you can use `this` in a class component and not in a function component. In a function component, the attributes you pass to it are collected in the first parameter, in your case `props`.